# Как передать содержимое файла в текстовое поле модели django?

Tags: django, django-model

Есть модель для иконок:

```
class Icon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    icon = models.FileField(upload_to='icons/', blank=True, null=True)
    inline_svg = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=???)
```

Файлы иконок преимущественно .svg формата, я хочу в поле `inline_svg` передавать содержимое соответствующего файла icon, чтобы на фронте использовать inline svg, а не `<img src>`. Подскажите как это реализовать?

Была идея сделать что-то подобное:

```
class Icon(models.Model):
    def svg(self):
        f = open(self.icon.url)
        return f.read()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    icon = models.FileField(upload_to='icons/', blank=True, null=True)
    inline_svg = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=svg())
```

код неверный.

Можно, конечно, получать содержимое файла через javascript, но мне кажется это как-то некрасиво(возможно не прав)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переопределяем метод save():

```
class Icon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    icon = models.FileField(upload_to='icons/', blank=True, null=True)
    inline_svg = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.icon.name.endswith('.svg'):
            self.inline_svg = self.icon.read()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```